# Airdrop between iOS and Mac, does it only work if both devices are mine?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ios, ipad, airdrop

I'll explain better,

I can use AirDrop from and to my iPhone and my MBP. My Mac sees my phone and my phone sees my Mac.

The problem is if my family members try to send me something on the computer, they don't see my computer in the AirDrop but only my phone whereas I can see them all from my Mac and can send them files?

So I am guessing only I can send files to my computer because they are both registered to me?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144

Comment: I was sitting right next to my wife and son on the same couch and i can see them on airdrop on my macbook and send them files but they cannot see my macbook. They are both in my contacts and mac airdrop is set to everyone and yet only my phone is able to send files to computer and see computer on airdop on iPhone while my wife and my son can only see my phone.

Answer (score 1):

When the person receiving lets everyone see their device, airdrop should work for you to see and send to them as long as you have airdrop on with any receive setting chosen on your device.

Brief excerpt from the [Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144) in the comment above:

- Make sure that the person you're sending to is nearby and within Bluetooth and Wi-Fi range.
- Check that you and the person you're sending to have Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turned on. If either of you have Personal Hotspot on, turn it off.
- Check if the person you're sending to has their AirDrop set to receive from Contacts Only. If they do, and you’re in their Contacts, they need to have your Apple ID's email address or mobile number in your contact card for AirDrop to work.
- If you're not in their Contacts, have them set their AirDrop receiving setting to Everyone in order to receive the file.

Comment: I was sitting right next to my wife and son on the same couch and i can see them on airdrop on my macbook and send them files but they cannot see my macbook. They are both in my contacts and mac airdrop is set to everyone and yet only my phone is able to send files to computer and see computer on airdop on iPhone while my wife and my son can only see my phone.